# Git documentation: about `revert` subcommand of `git add -i`

Tags: git, git-add

[Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) about the `revert` subcommand of `git add -i`:

> **revert**
>   This has a very similar UI to update, and the staged
>   information for selected paths are reverted to that **of the HEAD
>   version.**

Maybe I incorrectly understand this text... I understand this like:

> `revert` does the same like `git checkout -- file_name`.

But at practice I see `revert` only removes file from the staging area. Did I incorrect translat, or it is incorrect text in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the **subcommand revert** (on interactive mode) the **command revert** and **command reset**.

- The first one is the opposite of *git add*, and you will able to use only if you run *git add --interactive*
- The second one is used to revert **commits** (will add a new commit with the opposite operations of the reverted commit).
- The last one is like the git add subcommand revert (first one), I mean, undo *git add* command (unless you specify a commit, see documentation).

So if you want to really reset some file you have to use *git checkout -- HEAD filename*

---

From Documentation:

[Git Revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

[Git Reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

[Git CheckOut](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Is *command revert* mentioned like `HEAD version` at this case?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, answer fixed !
Let me know any concerns or doubts!